# Recovering database with filestream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlfilestream

I had a database setup with a filestream.  The filestream storage was on a separate drive than the datafiles.  The server was migrated to virtual, and the drive letter unknowingly changed.  The database went into 'Recovery Pending' mode.  I didn't realize at first what had happened, so I took it offline in hopes of bringing it back online.  That didn't work.  For other reasons, I couldn't change the drive letter back on the existing drive, so I added another with the original letter, copied the filestream data, but it still won't come online.   The following error:

> A file activation error occurred.  The physical file name 'E:\SQL
>   Data\AutoServiceATtachments\AutoService_Filestream' may be incorrect'

What should my next steps be?  This is SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who may come across this, I have figured it out. 
I backed up all the files, dropped the database, and then attached it again, with the following syntax:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [FileStreamDB] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamDB.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamDB_log.ldf' ),
FILEGROUP [FileStreamGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM DEFAULT 
( NAME = N'FileStreamDB_FSData', FILENAME = N'C:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamData' )
FOR ATTACH
GO
```